# Duplicate unicode entry error on the unique column - mysql

Tags: python, mysql, unicode

I have a table `Labels` with 2 columns:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| Column Name |     Type     |     Key     |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| id          | integer      | primary key |
| label       | varchar(255) | unique      |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

In this table, I already have a record as the following:
`id: 1, label: 'café'`

And now I want to add more record as the following:
`id: auto, label: 'cafe'`

But when I try to insert, duplicate error appear

```
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'cafe' for key 'label_2'") [SQL: u'INSERT INTO vocabulary (label) VALUES (%s)'] [parameters: (u'cafe',)]
```

Could you guys help me in that case?
Some more information about my database: character set: utf8, collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

UPDATE: create table

```
CREATE TABLE `labels` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `label` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `label_2` (`label`),
  KEY `label` (`label`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: It may be more complicated than this if somehow your Python code is not sending UTF-8 data to MySQL correctly.

Comment: Absolutely not, I already tried to execute the raw MySQL query `INSERT INTO labels (label) VALUES ("cafe");` => same error

Comment: Can you share with us the `CREATE TABLE` of your table?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: updated

Comment: Unique constraint do not allow duplicates.read the mysql unique manual.In your check the column characterset and the Connection charcter set you are using.If the connection is in different character set which does not support utf8,this error will occur

Comment: @MohanaPriyan: do you mean `cafe` is same with `café`?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: hope you can help me :)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: do you have any other idea?

Comment: What is the language of word `café`, french, other?

Comment: Yes, I do have an idea.  Try inserting `cafés` in a new, separate record.  Then query the table and check if the accented E made it across.

Comment: It is a matter of `COLLATE` used for the column. Apparently using the default collation does not help the DB server distinguish between a `e` and a `é`. Check the answer given below which points to the correct direction (don't know why it was downvoted!).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as `label` is unique key,you are not able to insert duplicate value in that column.
As you want to distinguish between `café` and `cafe` and then you need to use utf8_bin collation .
Try below query.

```
ALTER TABLE labels CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
ALTER TABLE labels CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Hope this will helps.

Comment: I think `cafe` is different with `café`. It is not duplicate

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh As tim said,it's due to UTF-8 encoding.You have to check once for same.

Comment: Don't think so, it not about Python sending data to MySQL. I already tried to execute the raw MySQL query from command-line

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh Just try udateted one.
It's worked for me.

Comment: This is it! It also worked on my end.

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh , you are correct. Unfortunately, what matters is not what *you* think, it's what *MySQL* thinks. In several collations, "è" and "e" are considered the same.

Comment: @SagarGangwal Thank you very much, I will try this

Comment: @VũTuấnAnh Your always welcome.

Comment: The column is `CHARACTER SET utf8`; the default `COLLATION` for that charset is `utf8_general_ci`, which does case folding and accent stripping, making `café` = `cafe` = `CAFE`.  With `utf8_bin` those are considered as different.